# dplyr filter by multiple columns not working

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(code = rep(1:10, each = 3 * 3),
             type = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 10 * 3),
             year = rep(1980:1982, each = 10 * 3),
             x = rnorm(90))

df <- df %>% dplyr::arrange(code, year, type)
```

I want to remove all rows where CODE where `type == a` and `code` is either 1, 3 or 4. I did this:

```
exclude.code <- c(1, 3, 4)

new.df <- df %>% dplyr::filter(!code %in% exclude.code & type != "a")
```

But this is removing all the types which is not equal to `a` even though I only want to remove those `a` where the code is either 1, 3 or 4. What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried the approach in the comment but it still did not work

```
head(df %>% dplyr::filter((!code %in% exclude.code) & type != "a"))

 code type year    x
  5    b 1981 -1.0564839
  5    b 1981  1.5385139
  5    b 1981  0.5709470
  5    b 1981  0.4728047
  5    b 1981 -0.3739578
  5    b 1981  0.6338270
```

Comment: Sorry this does not work as well

Comment: dplyr::filter(!(code %in% exclude.code) & (type != "a")). Positon of `!`?

Comment: Sorry doesn't work. Does it work on your computer?

Comment: `df %>%
dplyr::filter(  !((code %in% exclude.code) & (type == "a"))  )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this:

```
df %>% dplyr::filter( !((code %in% exclude.code) & (type == "a")) )
```

- this 
  `(code %in% exclude.code) & (type == "a")` gets you the ones you DONT WANT.
- then apply `!` on the whole thing to "remove" them.

Comment: This works now. Thank you

Comment: it was a little hard to understand. Ronak's comment was very helpful.